# A variant of betweenness problem

Tags: ds.algorithms, approximation-algorithms, csp

Is there any non-trivial approximation algorithm for a variant of [betweenness problem](http://www.nada.kth.se/~viggo/wwwcompendium/node255.html): namely, we want to minimize the number of unsatisfied triples rather than to maximize the number of satisfied ones?

Comment: You cannot hope for any multiplicative approximation because it is NP-complete to decide whether all triples can be simultaneously satisfied or not (the original, decision version of betweenness).

Comment: fair enough, but what if we allow some (small) additive error?

Comment: Then what is the difference between maximizing the number of satisfied triples and minimizing the number of unsatisfied triples?

Comment: I don't see how an algorithm with an additive error 1 for the minimization problem is implied by any known algorithm for the maximization version.

Comment: Well, that is because an algorithm with an additive error 1 in the minimization version is equivalent to an algorithm with an additive error 1 in the maximization version (which does not exist unless P=NP).

Comment: My bad. But then what if we allow both multiplicative and additive error, or allow an additive error to depend of OPT.

Answer (score 2):

The particular minimization version which you mentioned does not make much sense, because even deciding whether all triples can be satisfied simutaneously or not is NP-comlpete.  Also, it is easy to see that unless P=NP, for every choice of constants *k*<sub>1</sub> and *k*<sub>2</sub>, there is no polynomial-time approximation algorithm for the minimization version of the betweenness problem in the sense that it produces an assignment which violates at most (*k*<sub>1</sub>⋅OPT + *k*<sub>2</sub>) triples, where OPT is the minimum number of violated triples.  (Just consider the case where OPT=0.)  *[Edit: In an earlier revision, I stated that this follows from [CS98], but [CS98] was overkill for it.]*

On a tangentially related topic, if you consider the *additive* approximation of the *ratio* of (un)satisfied triples, the problem becomes much more interesting.  Chor and Sudan [CS98] showed that for every *s*∈(47/48,1), it is NP-complete to decide whether a given instance of the betweenness problem is satisfiable or no assignment satisfies more than *s* fraction of constraints.  In particular, the ratio version is NP-hard to approximate within any constant additive error less than 1/48, and this clearly applies equally to both the maximization version and the minimization version.

For more on approximation of a satisfaction ratio within an additive error, see my answer to the question “[Hardness of approximation - additive error](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/2421/hardness-of-approximation-additive-error)” by Raphael Clifford.

[CS98] Benny Chor and Madhu Sudan.  A geometric approach to betweenness.  *SIAM Journal on Discrete Mathematics*, 11(4):511–523, Nov. 1998.  DOI: [10.1137/S0895480195296221](http://dx.doi.org/10.1137/S0895480195296221).